# The data from json is not populated in my angular 8 app

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular8

My json looks as follows:

```
    {
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test name",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "img_url": "url",
            "field1": [
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "userId": 1,
                    "registeredAt": "2020-01-09T22:21:23.272",
                    "amount": 200
                }
            ],
            "field2": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "userId": 1,
                    "registeredAt": "2020-01-09T22:21:46.113",
                    "amount": 200
                }
            ],
            "creationDateTime": "2020-01-05T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "page": 0,
    "size": 30,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "last": true
}
```

and I want to populate with it my `angular 8` website.

In my `api.service.ts` I have:

```
getMyStructure(): Observable<HttpResponse<MyStructure[]>> { 
    return this.http.get<MyStructure[]>( 
        localUrl, { observe: 'response' }); 
}
```

and in `app.components.ts` I have:

```
myStructure: MyStructure[] = []; 

getMyStructure() { 
    this.api.getMyStructure() 
    .subscribe(function(resp) { 
        console.log(resp.body.length); //this prints undefined 
        console.log(resp.body) // this prints {content: Array, page: 0, size: 30, totalElements: 1, totalPages: 1, …} 
        this.myStructure = resp.body; 
    }); 
    console.log("after"); 
    console.log(this.myStructure.length); //this prints 0
```

Now, `myStructure` is an interface, that contains:

```
export interface Shelter {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    img_url: string;
    field1: string[];
    field2: string[];
    creationDateTime: string;
}
```

but the data inside `myStructure` somehow is not populated. I have no idea why, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API doesn't return `MyStructure[]` it returns:

*Please chose a better name for the interface*

```
interface SomeStructure {
  content: MyStructure[];
  page: number;
  size: number;
  totalElements: number;
  totalPages: number;
  last: boolean
}
```

**api.service.ts**

```js
getMyStructure(): Observable<HttpResponse<SomeStructure>> { 
    return this.http.get<SomeStructure>( 
        localUrl, { observe: 'response' }); 
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
myStructure: MyStructure[] = []; 

getMyStructure() { 
    this.api.getMyStructure() 
    .subscribe((resp) => { 
        this.myStructure = resp.body.content; 
    }); 
}
```

> Take note of the arrow function in the subscribe `.subscribe((resp) => {`

Comment: hm, that makes sense... btw. are you sure there should be `return this.http.get<MyStructure[]>` in api.service.ts instead of `return this.http.get<SomeStructure>` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the console.log inside the **`subscribe`** part of the code, otherwise as it gets executed first, you will see it as 0. Change it as,

```
.subscribe(function(resp) { 
        console.log(resp.body.length); //this prints undefined 
        console.log(resp.body) // this prints {content: Array, page: 0, size: 30, totalElements: 1, totalPages: 1, …} 
        this.myStructure = resp.body; 
        console.log("after"); 
        console.log(this.myStructure.length);  
    });
```

EDIT:

As I see you want to display the content array on the front end, so you need to assign the data as,

```
 this.myStructure = resp.body.content;
```

Comment: ok, that makes sense, but it still does not populate the data to the frontend. In my `app.component.html` I have the code: `<ul><li *ngFor="let product of myStructure"><h2>{{product.name}} / ${{product.email}}</h2></li></ul>` and even though I see the data from console.log in the console, I don't see it in html code. Do you know why?

Comment: thank you for the answer, but when I put `resp.body.content` the project does not compile, there's an error `TS2339: Property 'content' does not exist on type 'MyStructure[]'.` I think it's because of the declaration of `getMyStructure` method in `api.service.ts` - I don't know how should I change it though

Comment: change subscribe(function(resp : any) {

Comment: thank you, I changed it, the project compiled, but I still don't see any data in html, I wonder why :| it seems like the data in html file (`myStructure`) is empty :(

Comment: can you print the response of console.log(resp.body);

Comment: thank you for your input! The other answer solved the problem though, but I really appreciate your help!